# Spotify API Authorization for cron job

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, spotify

I'm creating a node.js application that will update playlists (owned by an account in which I have credentials) daily. According to the Spotify documentation, to add tracks to a playlist (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/add-tracks-to-playlist/), authorization must be supplied using oauth2.

I'm struggling to find a way to do this completely server side with no redirects/etc. It seems like if I can get a refresh token, I can just use that?

I've been looking at the spotify web api node module (https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node), oauth.io, and the spotify api.

Any ideas would be appreciated! There is only one account that will have to be authenticated, so it could be hard-coded at least for now.

Answer (score 9):

You've picked the correct authorization flow - [Authorization Code](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow), since you need an access token that's connected to the user who owns the playlists you're updating. This of course also gives you the ability to refresh the token whenever you need to. (The expiration time is one hour, but you don't need to refresh the access token until your application actually needs to use it.)

As a sidenote, the [Client Credentials flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) is meant for server to server communication that doesn't require a user's permission, e.g. to search, read a playlist, or retrieve new releases. The [Implicit Grant flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow) is meant to be used in frontends, and doesn't allow you to refresh the token.

> I'm struggling to find a way to do this completely server side with no redirects/etc. It seems like if I can get a refresh token, I can just use that?

Once you have the refresh token you can continue to use it to retrieve new access tokens, which can be done without any user interaction. You need to do some preparation work to retrieve the refresh token though.

Following the steps describing the [Authorization Code flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow), you first need to direct the playlist's owner to a URL on Spotify's account server.

The documentation contains the following example URL:

> GET https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=5fe01282e44241328a84e7c5cc169165&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=34fFs29kd09

Simply replace the `client_id` and `redirect_uri` with your application's information. Also modify the `scope` parameter to match the scopes you need, which from my understanding of your use case is `playlist-read-private,playlist-modify-private,playlist-read-collaborative` since you want to be able to read and modify all of the user's playlists. Supplying `state` is not required.

Using spotify-web-api-node you can generate this URL using the [createAuthorizeURL](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/blob/master/src/spotify-web-api.js#L1240) method, but since you're only doing this once it's unnecessary to write code for it.

Instead, simply open the URL in your browser.

If done successfully, you'll be taken through a little login dance where your application asks for your permission to read and modify your playlists. When this is completed, Spotify's account service will redirect the browser to your `redirect_uri` URL with a `code` query parameter included as described in step 3 in the Authorization Guide.

However, since you're only doing this once, it would be enough to start a webserver on your own machine, set your application's `redirect_uri` to your localhost, and complete the login flow. Have a look at [web-api-auth-examples](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples) for a ready-made node.js application that fires up an express server and reads the authorization code.

Once you've got the code, you can trade it for an access token using cURL as it's done in step #4 in the Authorization Guide, or use the code in the web-api-auth-examples repository.

Finally, with the tokens retrieved (step #5), you can start to use the Web API with the access token, and get a new one when it expires using the request in step #7.

[spotify-web-api-node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node) has a helper method to refresh the token. Search the main documentation for the `refreshAccessToken` method.

Comment: Thanks! It was the curl step(4/5) that I was missing.  I've now got a refresh token and should be good to go. Thanks! Hopefully I won't have any follow-up questions.

Comment: Hi Michael-- one follow-up question. I'm adding songs, and some of them are successfully posting. However, some of the requests are returning 500 errors: `{ name: 'WebapiError',
  message: 'Server error.',
  statusCode: 500 }`  I'm not sure why this is and why it's only some of the requests. Is there a way to get more useful information from this error?  I'm using the addTracksToPlaylist function from the spotify-web-api-node, but had the same issue when I was doing the requests directly.

Comment: This is most likely due to a known issue on Spotify's side relating to some playlists, usually playlists with a lot of revisions (additions, deletions, reordering). The same issue can be recreated when retrieving a user's playlists, or when retrieving a playlist or its tracks. So you need to handle this in your application, but I advise that you retry the request if it does happen.

Comment: Ok. I'm also now getting some Rate limit exceeded responses. What is the rate limit exactly?  Having trouble finding in in the docs.

Comment: There's [some documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/#rate-limiting) on rate limits and what you can do to handle being limited, both in terms of making more efficient requests and how to know when you can try again. The exact rate limits are not published as we don't want to commit to a specific limit yet. Given your Stack Overflow 'points', I'm assuming you're new here - Welcome! If you have questions not directly related to the original one, feel free to create a new question instead of commenting. This allows others to find both question and answer more easily.

Answer (score 2):

This use case is slightly mentioned in the [FAQ section of the Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#frequently-asked-questions-about-authorization).

As you said, you need to obtain a refresh token using the authorization code flow. For that you will need to carry out the OAuth process using your user account, the client_id of the app you have registered, and the scopes you need (it will vary depending on whether the playlist is private or public). Then, take the refresh token you have obtained and the client secret key of your app, and you can obtain access tokens without the need of the login form.

This related StackOverflow question might help too [Spotify automated playlist management with PHP back-end and rate limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722013/spotify-automated-playlist-management-with-php-back-end-and-rate-limits/25725414#25725414)